# Scrapy InitSpider unable to click correct login button

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to log into a Tor forum with a Scrapy InitSpider however I have encountered the following problem.

Below is my code that handles the login:

```
def init_request(self):
  ##This function is called before crawling starts
  return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

def login(self, response):
  ##Generates a login request
  return FormRequest.from_response(
    response, 
    formdata = {
      'user': 'username', 
      'passwrd': 'password', 
      'cookielength':'9999'
    }, 
    clickdata = {
      'type': 'submit', 
      'class': 'button_submit', 
      'value': 'Login'
    }, 
    callback = self.check_login_response
  )

def check_login_response(self, response):
  ##Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are successfully logged in.
  print(str(response.body))

  if "Hello" in response.body:
    self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
    ##Now the crawling can begin..
    self.initialized()
```

And I receive the following error:

```
raise ValueError('No clickable element matching clickdata: %r' % (clickdata,))
ValueError: No clickable element matching clickdata: {'type': 'submit', 'class': 'button_submit', 'value': 'Login'}
```

Once I remove the attribute 'value': 'Login' from the clickdata list the spider then selects the first clickable element on the page, and not the element that would log in, and the login fails.

Below is the relevant HTML for the login portion of the page:

```
<div class="roundframe"><br class="clear">
  <dl>
    <dt>Username:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input type="text" name="user" size="20" value="" class="input_text">
    </dd>
    <dt>Password:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input type="password" name="passwrd" value="" size="20" class="input_password">
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>Minutes to stay logged in:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input type="text" name="cookielength" size="4" maxlength="4" value="120" class="input_text">
    </dd>
    <dt>Always stay logged in:</dt>
    <dd>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cookieneverexp" class="input_check" onclick="this.form.cookielength.disabled = this.checked;">
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button_submit">
  </p>
  <p class="smalltext">
    <a href="http://thehub7xbw4dc5r2.onion/index.php?action=reminder">
      Forgot your password?
    </a>
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" name="d49bd52b3" value="f29d515eca1c0199840161f01d940973">
  <input type="hidden" name="hash_passwrd" value="">
</div>
```

Could anyone tell me how I can resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `clickdata` don't work (it's really poorly described and may be it only works with `name` attribute) but this code works for me:

```
def login(self, response):
    ##Generates a login request
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
      response,
      formid='frmLogin',
      formdata = {
        'user': 'username',
        'passwrd': 'password',
        'cookielength':'9999'
      },
      # clickdata = {
      #   'type': 'submit',
      #   'class': 'button_submit',
      #   'value': 'Login'
      # },
      callback = self.check_login_response
    )
```